# Display Logs from a Particular Server using C++ code

Tags: c++, udp

I have logs coming from multiple server and i need to display logs from only one server. How should i filter the logs and get to display only logs from one server only. What i have is storing the logs from multiple server in the vector container, and i need to filter out from them the logs from one server only, and need to  display it using c++ code. How to solve this problem ?

I am attaching my code herewith what i have tried so far.

Thanks in advance.

```
void ABC::fnGetData()
{
   int ByteReceived=0;
   CString  msg;
 const CString servername = "XYZ";


BufLength = 256;

while(1)
{
    ByteReceived = recvfrom(ReceivingSocket, ReceiveBuf, BufLength,0, NULL, NULL);    // Receives a datagram 

   if(ByteReceived > 0 )
   {
     msg.Format("Server: The data is  (%s) \n",ReceiveBuf);
     udp.push_back(msg);
     std::vector<CString>::const_iterator it = std::find(udp.begin(), udp.end(), "XYZ");

            std::cout << "Found " << *it << " in the vector" << std::endl;

                GetField(e_Logs + iCount)->SetValueString(udp[nIndex]);
                iCount++;
                nIndex++; 

             if(iCount >= 20) 
             {
                    iCount = 0;
                    Recalculate();
             }                        
    }
    if(ByteReceived < 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}        


 void ABC:: Recalculate()
 {
   fnGetData();
   StartRecalcTimer(3,true);
   return;
 }
```

Comment: Uh? Depends on HOW you are storing the logs, and how you want to filter it... (E.g. do you ALWAYS want to filter only one, or do you want to show all logs, selected logs from several machine, filter on certain types of logs, etc, etc). Also, perhaps show us what you have tried...

Comment: Yes sir, i need to filter logs of only one type only say from server "XYZ".

Comment: Assuming you use `recvfrom`, you have an argument that is filled in with the address of the peer that you can use for filtering. *Or* if the logs themselves contain server-information you can look at the packets you receive.

Comment: How to apply filter though in c++, i am posting my code herewith above.

Comment: ok sir, is there where i have to do some  changes ??

Comment: Being UDP communication, the data you receive is usually formatted in some way. You need to know that format, and you will be able to parse out the data you need. And you need to use the *exact* data you receive and parse it, not your "cooked up" format you made by putting it in a string like you do. Is the data you receive even textual?

Comment: Not really sir, it consists of many things like userid, client ip etc. What changes i need to do in the above code to display the log from one server only.

Comment: So is it a binary structure? Then you need to read it into a structure, and then you can easily check the structure member fields and use them as filter.

Comment: No Sir, it's not a binary structure, what i am getting is logs from the multiple servers of my company and i need to display one of particular server only.

Comment: How to apply filter to logs coming from multiple server and need to display only particular type??